# Get specific html tag

Tags: php

Okey, the table row contains this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <img>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And I need to only get the images out, and theres no other way to retreive these files. I know, its a stupid input. But is there a way to get only the img-tag out?

Comment: Do you have to use php? jQuery could do this very very fast with only a few lines of code.

Comment: PHP can do this very quickly with only a few lines of code too (as can any other language with a DOM library).

Comment: 1. this is a list, not a table.
2. With what script language do you want get those tags? Javascript or PHP?

Comment: I dont have to use PHP, If jQuery can do this with a few simple lines, that could help :). Yeah, I know that isnt a table-tag. I mean table as in database

Comment: Get them out as in: strip them, or get them out as in: retrieve them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using regex but thats not a good solution for this,

Use this instead:

```
echo strip_tags($html, '<img>');
```

Note: $html contains all the html you want to parse

Answer (score 0):

I assume this piece of HTML is in one variable and you want to "parse" the result? If so, you could use something like:

```
preg_match_all('/<img.+?src="(.+)"/', $html, $matches);
```

In matches you will find the sources (or entire image tags).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strip_tags()` to get the specific one or more tags

Syntax:

```
string strip_tags ( string $str [, string $allowable_tags ] )
```

Code:

```
 $text ="<ul>
    <li>
      <img>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img>
    </li>
</ul>";

  echo strip_tags($text, '<img>');
```

Ref: http://www.php.net/strip_tags